# Is it possible to speed up/slow down the preview playback of an animation in the Timeline?

Tags: animation, timeline

Using the **Action Editor** and in **Pose Mode**, I am editing the animation of my armature at 30 FPS. Maintaining that framerate, I would like a slower preview of my animation (like play at 50% normal speed)  in the **Timeline** when I press Alt+A. Is this possible? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6293/599

Comment: I would argue that this is not a duplicate question. I saw that question before posting this and as I understand it, that question resolves the issue of playback at a lower framerate. I would like to know if it's possible to have a playback at a lower *speed*, as if time is slowed down.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1053/599

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the *Time Remapping*. Since 2.8, go into *Properties > Output > Dimensions > Time Remapping*. Previously in *Properties > Render > Dimensions*:

[image]

It expresses the animation speed as a ratio of `original speed / new speed`, where the speed is expressed in frames. So to reduce the speed 50%, you can use `50/100`, `1/2`, `100/200` or any other ratio which reduces to `1/2`, i.e. `1 frame for every 2 frames`.

[image]

Note that while frames are used as the units, this setting will interpolate animations on subframes. Not all features support this, see [Which animation features don't support sub-frames?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/36605/599) for details.

Comment: Will this apply to a music which is playing too?

Comment: @AndréSantos No. You'll have to adjust the pitch accordingly (put in the time remapping values as `old/new`). If you want to change the tempo without affecting the pitch, then you'll have to [do it in something like audacity](http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/change_tempo.html).